# Fixed header issue on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile

Hi I have the following problem. I have a website that is suited for mobile use and is still on development. Now, the issue is that the fixed header behaves different on different pages, on one page gets the fixed behavior and on the other scrolls a little. Check the links on a mobile device and scroll the pages to see the issue.

[Product Page](https://www.entrenamiento.com/es/producto/titulo-del-producto-000000/)

[Homepage](https://www.entrenamiento.com/es/)

So, my question is, what makes the header to scroll a little on the Product Page?

The css used to style the header is as follows:

```
.small-navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 130;
}
```

Comment: They work identically on iPad Safari

Comment: Thanks for testing @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Did you create CSS for mobile devices?
If you don't then first you need to do that by device width or media query

Comment: The header only shows on mobile. So the header css specifically affects it and no other content or elements.

Comment: Then what is your main question?

Comment: My question is why if the header is fixed to the top is scrolling a little bit on mobile browsers.